# Read and write from S3 within SvelteKit using AWS SDK v3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, sveltekit, aws-sdk-js

I'm trying to use `@aws-sdk/client-s3` to read and write some files to an S3 bucket. However, when trying to do this within SvelteKit I get this error:

```
CredentialsProviderError: Could not load credentials from any providers
    at /repo-location/node_modules/@aws-sdk/credential-provider-node/dist-cjs/defaultProvider.js:13:11
```

This looks to be because it is looking for `process.env` variables (among other places).

Is there a way for me to do something like this (I know the below is incorrect)?

```
import { S3Client } from '@aws-sdk/client-s3';
import { env } from '$env/dynamic/private';

const client = new S3Client({ env, region });
```

How can I get it to use SvelteKit's way of handling environment variables instead? Or am I approaching this the wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any problem with providing static credential values via .env files.

I've tried creating an S3 Client myself and loading the credentials from the .env, [following this example in the Svelte docs](https://learn.svelte.dev/tutorial/env-static-private).

Here's my .env file, located at the root of the project:

```
ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'MY_ACCESS_KEY'
ACCESS_KEY_SECRET = 'MY_SECRET'
```

Here's how to create the S3 client using JS:

```js
import { S3Client } from '@aws-sdk/client-s3';
import { ACCESS_KEY_ID, ACCESS_KEY_SECRET } from '$env/static/private';

const client = new S3Client({
    region:'eu-south-1',
    credentials: {
        accessKeyId: ACCESS_KEY_ID,
        secretAccessKey: ACCESS_KEY_SECRET
    }
});
```

However, please note that in a real-world environment, you shouldn't hardcode credentials.
[Refer to the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/setting-credentials-node.html) to determine the most suitable method depending on where your code is running.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I wasn't aware of the `credentials` parameter. The AWS documentation is pretty terrible right now.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Filippo, I got the issue resolved. Here's the full TypeScript code for me to get it working.

```ts
import { S3Client, GetObjectCommand, PutObjectCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-s3";
import {
  AWS_REGION,
  AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
  AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
  S3_BUCKET_NAME,
} from "$env/static/private";

const s3 = new S3Client({
  region: AWS_REGION,
  credentials: {
    accessKeyId: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    secretAccessKey: AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
  }
});

const getKey = (path: string) => `saved/${path}.json`;

export async function saveToS3(path: string, data: JSON) {
  // TODO add some sort of abuse prevention
  const key = getKey(path);
  const uploadCommand = new PutObjectCommand({
    Bucket: S3_BUCKET_NAME,
    Key: key,
    Body: data,
    ACL: "public-read",
  });
  try {
    const response = await s3.send(uploadCommand);
    console.log("S3 upload success ", response);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("S3 upload error ", error);
  }
};

export async function loadFromS3(path: string): Promise<JSON> {
  // TODO add some sort of abuse prevention
  const key = getKey(path);
  const getCommand = new GetObjectCommand({
    Bucket: S3_BUCKET_NAME,
    Key: key,
  });
  try {
    const data = await s3.send(getCommand);
    const str = await data.Body.transformToString();
    console.log("S3 download success ", str);
    return str;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("S3 download error ", error);
    return <JSON>(error);
  }
}
```